# Construct function from strings

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was wondering if something like this is possible. Let's use 'canvas' for example:

```js
(function(){
function Canvas(canvas){
  this.canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.testMethod('fillRect',[10,10,10,10]);
}
Canvas.prototype.testMethod = function(method,params){
this.method = method;
this.params = params;

this.ctx.method.apply(this.ctx, params);

}
var canvas = new Canvas();
})()
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Of course it doesn't work but I wonder if it's possible to dynamically construct functions in this way. What I would like to achive is sort of user interface where I would input method name and parameters and they would be executed in specific context (CanvasRenderingContext2D in this particular example)

Comment: I think with closure and module its not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing this line

```
this.ctx.method.apply(this.ctx, params);
```

to

```
this.ctx[method].apply(this.ctx, params);
```

since canvas's property ( whose value is a function) name is stored in a variable.

for example, if your object is

```
var obj = {
 a: function(){console.log(1)}
}
```

you can invoke

```
obj.a();
```

or if you have

```
var b = "a";
obj[b]();
```

Comment: It does work:) but I don't quite understand why...

Comment: @przemoo83 do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: No I mean it works fine I just don't understand the mechanics behind the scenes..

Comment: @przemoo83 which part you didn't understand?

Comment: 'this.ctx[method]' - the part that makes 'string' into a function :P

Comment: @przemoo83 i have explained the same, let me know if there are more doubts

Comment: Yes bracket notation...I sometimes forget the basics (#facepalm). Thanks for clearing that out:)